# Bump acorn from 6.4.0 to 6.4.1 #1

Tags: react-ssr

GitHub set a message for me, say: Bump acorn from 6.4.0 to 6.4.1 #1, and I merge, my project is ok?

my project is react-ssr demo, why send me this message?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Dependabot helps you keep your dependencies up to date. It works with most popular languages.

Every day, Dependabot checks your dependency files for outdated requirements and opens individual pull requests for any it finds. You review the PRs, merge them, and get to work on the latest, most secure releases.

Dependabot is owned and maintained by GitHub.